# How to close modal popup by clicking outside the modal-content in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, jquery, widgets, popup

I have created a popup successfully by using Magento 2 `modal` code as i added below but now i want to close the popup even customer click on outside the pop-up or blur area.

Is there any existing feature or code can help us to achieve this?

Can anyone help on this.

```
var showFinanceCaclculator = $('div#finance-pre-calculated-values')
    .modal({
          autoOpen: false,
          buttons: [],
          clickableOverlay: true,
          focus: '',
          innerScroll: false,
          modalClass: '',
          modalLeftMargin: 60,
          responsive: true,
          title: 'Estimated Finance Terms',
          type: 'popup'
         });
        $("#show-finance-button").click(function () {
           showFinanceCaclculator.modal("openModal");
       });
```

Comment: please look at here for the solution http://magentocodes.blogspot.in/2017/10/how-to-close-modal-popup-clicking.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We fixed this issue in a custom theme using a RequireJS mixin by adding the following files:

*app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Ui/web/js/model/modal-mixin.js*

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function ($, wrapper) {
    'use strict';

    return function (modal) {

        modal.prototype.openModal = wrapper.wrap(modal.prototype.openModal, function(original) {

            var result = original();
            $('.' + this.options.overlayClass).appendTo('.modal-popup._show');
            //Setting z-index of inner-wrap to 900 so that it is actually clickable and not hiding behind the overlay
            $('.modal-inner-wrap').css('z-index', 900);
            return result;
        });

        return modal;
    };
});
```

*app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/requirejs-config.js*

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal': {
                'Magento_Ui/js/model/modal-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Read more here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7399

Answer (score 8):

Hi just place the below code in the footer file or any file which is common on all pages and it will do your job. I was also going to the same issue and came out with this and it works perfectly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'],
    function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
$("body").click
(
  function(e)
  {
      var checkclass = e.target.className ;  
        if (checkclass.indexOf("_show") >= 0){

                    $( ".action-close" ).trigger( "click" );
        }
      //console.log(e.target.className);

  }
);
    }); });
</script>
```

Comment: In e.target.className ,what class should i give here

Comment: You just need to use the same class name as above code. just copy paste the code and it should work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although above answers relies on js mixin solution but the thing is that magento already closes the modal when you click outside the modal window by triggering **closeModal** method on **outerClickHandler** function provided as an option.

The neat css trick that the default luma theme does is to prevent click on modal-popup by setting pointer-events to none and then again re-enabling it on child **modal-inner-wrap** element by setting pointer-events to auto.

In this way modal will be always in front of modals-overlay and still modals-overlay will be always clickable.

Check if somehow these properties missed/changed in your custom theme.

```
.modal-popup {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modal-inner-wrap {
   pointer-events: auto;
}
```